# Orchard custom forms override Create.cshtml for one content type only

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have created a custom content type ContactForm and I'm using the Custom Forms module.

Is there a way to override the Create.cshtml file only for the ContactForm?

I tried Create-ContactForm.cshtml but it's not working.

Comment: Try Content.Edit-ContactForm.cshtml

Comment: @devqon, this is what the shape tracer gave me, but I need the same for the Create.cshtml

Comment: Create.cshtml is a controller view, not a shape. You should however be able to override it I think

Comment: Create.cshtml uses the Shape to render the editor, so it should also use the Content.Edit-ContactForm.cshtml

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I'm digging in the wrong direction...

Answer (score 0):

If you want alternate view to be displayed follow the steps.
1. Enable Designer tools module.
2. View the page where create.cshtml is displayed.
3. You will see see small minus sign in right bottom corner, click it to enable shape tracing.
4. Trace the shape for which you want alternate view.
5. check shapes tab, there will be multiple alternate options availbale. click on create for appropriate one.
6. find and edit that template in visual studio.

first of all read about alternates and shape tracing.
some reference for you.
http://devhammer.net/blog/Customize-Orchard-CMS-with-Designer-Tools
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates